# how to load image in between .animate() function in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I am trying to build jquery with .animate and setInterval function as follow.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#animate1").animate({'margin-left':'150px','margin-bottom':'50px'},2000)
  },300);
    });
```

this animation moves my image from bottom to left. If i want to display an image only during this animation not display after this animation then how can i put that..?? my html is as follow

`<div>
<div id="animate1"><img src="img/chotu.png" style="height:200px; width:200px;"/>
</div></div>`

Comment: Why can't you simply chain these actions: fade in, animate, fade out.

Comment: how can i put all three together?

Comment: I posted an answer to show how to chain things...

Comment: thanks arkascha...!!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you simply chain these actions: fade in, animate, fade out?

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/45ky6pgw/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="animate1">
    <img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/riL/xdz/riLxdzRoT.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
#animate1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
#animate1 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#animate1")
      .fadeIn('slow')
      .animate({'margin-left':'50px','margin-bottom':'50px'},2000)
      .fadeOut('slow');
  }, 2000)
});
```

You can see the "chaining" of the three methods `fadeIn()`, `animate()` and `fadeOut()` in the JS code.

Answer (score 0):

I exaclty looking for this...!!

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    setInterval(function(){ 
   $("#animate1").fadeIn('slow').animate({'margin-left':'150px','margin-bottom':'50px'},2000).fadeOut();
   $("#animate1").fadeIn('slow').animate({'margin-bottom':'0px','margin-left':'-150px'},2000).fadeOut();
  },300);
    });
```

and after fisrt .fadeOut() function i want to change my background-image opacity..!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because your background div class or div id should be same to do that or you can do it with jquery chaining. But jquery chaining plays animation one by one. So, you can do it with CSS transform or animation also.